# Log error of script to a file along with the date and time

Tags: bash, error-handling, logging

I can use `2> errorLogFile` to log error of running script to a file right? my question is how to log the date and time of error along with error?

for example:

```
$ cat myScript
2> errorLogFile
..... # rest of the script
```

this is how the error file should look like:

```
$ cat errorLogFile
21 Nov 2015 2:00 PM some error happened
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect `stderr` to a process substitution which processes `stderr` and outputs the processed lines to the log.

For example, this script will print 5 lines to `stdout` and 5 lines to `stderr`, redirecting `stderr` to a process susbstitution which processes `stderr` and outputs the processed lines to a file named "log" in the current working directory (mind that the syntax to redirect `stderr` is `exec 2> [...]`, not `2> [...]`):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> >(perl -pe '$x=`date "+%d %b %Y %H:%M %p"`;chomp($x);$_=$x." ".$_' >log)
for i in {1..5}; do
    sleep 1
    echo "STDOUT message #$i"
    echo "STDERR message #$i" >&2
done
exit 0
```

The process substitution invokes Perl, which appends the current date and time in that format to each line and outputs them to a file named "log" in the current working directory.

```
% bash script.sh
STDOUT message #1
STDOUT message #2
STDOUT message #3
STDOUT message #4
STDOUT message #5
% cat log
02 Nov 2015 20:15 PM STDERR message #1
02 Nov 2015 20:15 PM STDERR message #2
02 Nov 2015 20:15 PM STDERR message #3
02 Nov 2015 20:15 PM STDERR message #4
02 Nov 2015 20:15 PM STDERR message #5
```